# Allure report: How Allure save/get both results from different test

Tags: java, testing, jasmine, allure, test-reporting

I'm new in Allure report framework
I'm working( run ) on two tests and getting the results from TestNG and Jasmine Protractor and Everything is working. My question is how Allure collects the results from the two tests is using Database or any server or how.So my company wants to know architecture of how it actually works or how it stores test results because the company needs to have test history for long periods of time.
If anyone has any answers it would help.
Thank you!